# Intensity of light from a hexadecimal value of color

Tags: java, graphics

In physic unit of light is the [Candle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela).

I already have the hexadecimal  value of a color for instance  `#030101`, but i want to know `Light intensity` of every color. How can i get it?

Is the concept of **Brightness** in Photoshop trying to model **Candel** for computer?

Comment: Umm, surely this depends on the brightness setting of your monitor?

Comment: see the documentation of [RGBtoHSB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB(int,int,int,float[])).

Comment: I may have misread the question... `RGBtoHSB` will give you the _relative_ brightness of a color.  As @OliCharlesworth pointed out, though, the actual physical measurement of light intensity is something a computer has no way of knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such conversion is possible.  The actual intensity will depend on settings on the output device, such as the brightness setting on the monitor, and the color space being used.

There is an abstract intensity measure in the [HSB color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), but it just specifies a value between 0 and some arbitrary upper value (i.e. 0.0 to 1.0 if using floats or 0-255 for a typical color picker).  The two extremes represent only "the darkest color possible" and "the lightest color possible", both of which depend on the output device and have no absolute meaning in terms of [candelas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela).

Comment: The OP could call this *relative candelas* and have it as a percentage of a human-input monitor brightness

Comment: @Pureferret Could you please give me a detailed answered ?
Thanks

Comment: @Pureferret Anything like that would have to take into account the gamma curve as well. The mapping from value 0 to value MAX (1.0, 255, whatever) is not linear.  I.e. 0.5 is not necessarily 1/2 the luminous intensity of 1.0.  Note also that the definition of a candela involves the frequency response curve of the human eye and is pegged to green light at ~555nm.  This is an extremely complex and non-linear relationship.